# Delete entire line from file if line contains digits in 4 columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm quite new in bash, and have faced with a situation where I need to parse a huge file, but not everything is interesting to me. The file contains a list of data separated by '.' delimiter, number of columns are various from line to line.

The following pattern I would like to exclude from my output: if 1st 4 columns contains numbers.

Here is an example (only 1st row shall be excluded from output):

```
123.123.123.123.abc.abc.abc
123.123.123.abc.abc
abc.abc.123.123.abc
```

I have looked for some solution using awk, but no success so far.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: not really.. thanks for a reply. grep solution mentioned below works for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**grep** solution:

```
grep -Ev '^([0-9]+\.){4}' file
```

The output:

```
123.123.123.abc.abc
abc.abc.123.123.abc
```

Comment: I know. Haven't chance to Accept due to time limitation (10min) after @RomanPerekhrest reply.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F"." 'match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){next} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
123.123.123.abc.abc
abc.abc.123.123.abc
```

**Explanation:** Making field separator as DOT(.) and then using match functionality of awk and looking for continuous 4 fields which have digits in them, so if yes then using next(which will skip all the further statements). Then mentioning 1 here to print the lines apart from the lines which are having matching patterns.

Comment: np, glad that it helped you. Whenever you get repo/time you could do it then.

Answer (score 0):

In awk you can use two alternatives less than or equal to like this:

```
awk -F. 'NF<6' file or
awk -F. 'NF==5' file

123.123.123.abc.abc
abc.abc.123.123.abc
```